# Mathematical Ambiguity in Electric field at centre of a uniformly charged hollow hemisphere

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, calculus

So, there is a question in the book "Problems in General Physics" by I.E. Irodov to calculate the electric field at the centre of a hollow hemisphere.

I was able to solve this question and also matched my solution with the solution booklet, and it was all correct.

But now I am stuck with a conceptual or mathematical doubt (I don't know what this is), and it is troubling me as I've used a similar method to obtain the centre of mass of a hollow hemisphere and in a few more derivations.

Now, in order to find the answer, we need to first consider an elemental ring, find the charge $\mathrm{d}q$ it contains, and then apply the result of electric field due to ring and integrate it from $0$ to $π/2$.

But when I find the width of the ring by applying the formula of arc length L, ${R\theta=L},$ then I get my width, $\mathrm{d}r=R \mathrm{d}\theta$ where $R$ is the radius of the hemisphere and $r$ is the radius of my elemental ring. All good till now.

But when we express $r$ in terms of $\mathrm{R}$, we get $r=R \sin\theta$ (Consider the angle $\theta$ from the vertical).

Now, if I differentiate $r$ to find $\mathrm{d}r$ I get, $\mathrm{d}r=R \cos\theta \mathrm{d}\theta$.

So now we have two values of $\mathrm{d}r,$ but which do we apply? Earlier I did not notice much and applied $\mathrm{d}r=R\mathrm{d}\theta$ and got all my answers correct, but now, I notice that $dr$ can also be mathematically expressed as $\mathrm{d}r=R\cos\theta \mathrm{d}\theta,$ so I am a little confused.

Also, both the values of $dr$ are possible only in the case of small angles, because as we know for small angles, $\sin\theta\approx\theta$. So is this derivation valid only for small angles?

I hope that I am able to explain my doubt. If not, then I will edit and will upload the picture.

Please help, Thankyou.

EDIT 1 - Here is the picture. It is a little bit blurry but will serve the purpose I guess.

[image]

Here the width is, $dr = Rdθ$ as I've mentioned and $r = Rsinθ$.

EDIT 2 - Changed the limit of integration from pi to pi/2.

Comment: Can it be due to that: r = R * sinθ is not a general statement but only valid for very small values of θ. This would make cosθ equal to 1 in dr=Rcosθdθ, leaving us with dr=Rdθ.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but to me it looks like the two dr's are two different things. As you see, one is 'on' the sphere, the other is 'inside' sphere. They become almost the same thing when θ is very small.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you write in the same way two different lengths: the width of the ring $dL=Rdθ$ and the variation in the radius of the ring when the angle varies.

Indeed, it is the width of the ring $dL$ that must be taken into account to find its charge.

EDIT :
The surface of the sphere is tilted on the vertical axis. You can easily see that the angle with the horizontal is $θ$. So, by projecting, we must find $dr=dLcos(θ)$

Comment: I think both are same. The inner and outer radius of the the elemental ring will be $r$ and $r+dr$ right? So the width = $dr$? Even my teacher did the derivation in the same way. I think I am committing a mistake in visualizing the elemental ring

Comment: I have added a small edit to be more expiclit.

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about the wall thickness of the hemisphere. All the charge is assumed to be on a very thin layer on the surface with *surface charge density* σ, which is per area, not per volume. *Note that charges on an ideal conductor repel each other to the surface.*

It looks like you assume Rdθ represents the very small difference between the 'radii' of two adjacent <s>rings</s> circles which are of radius Rsinθ. These <s>rings</s> circles are on the same surface of the sphere and their 'radii' has nothing to do with the 'width' mentioned. Their radii are in the horizontal plane while the width on the figure is <s>on the vertical direction</s> actually a curve on the hemisphere. As a simplified -but not exact- analogy, the area you crossed is a cylinder with radius Rsinθ and infinitesimal height (width) Rdθ.

As a different way to express it, Rsinθ is inside the sphere while the width Rdθ is always on the sphere. When θ is so small, Rsinθ is almost on the sphere. As θ converges to 0, Rsinθ converges to a point 'on' the sphere.

Comment: So does that mean $dr ≠ Rdθ$, $dl = Rdθ$ and the area dA of the ring (since it is a hemisphere) is, $dA = rdl$, $rdr$ would represent the area of the ring where $r+dr$ is the radius of outer circle of the ring and it lies outside the hemisphere. This is what I understood.

Comment: It is about how you would name the variables. But the inner or outer circle terms are irrelevant in this question. If anything, it would be upper or lower circles -both on the outer surface of the hemisphere. We are trying to find the area between the circles, then we will multiply that area with the charge density σ. The closer the circles the more it resembles a cylinder -eventually it turns into a ring. But it is not clear to me why you take the integral from 0 to pi. I think it should be from 0 to pi/2.

Comment: Yeah it should be pi/2, I was writing the question hastily so I wrote 0 to pi. And thanks for the solution, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Vincent's answer, although I see you could use a bit of help understanding. You write that $r=Rsin\theta$. That's correct, and $r$ represents the  radius of the elemental ring. So what do you think will $dr$ represent? It will denote a **small change in the radius of the elemental ring**. But we are not concerned with changes in the radius of the ring. However, we do need the thickness/width of the ring, which is given by $Rd\theta$. As noted by answers above, you don't have an misconception, it's just that you are mixing up variable names.